# IE6 background-image margin/padding/spacing issue

Tags: css, background-image

I'm currently designing a page with a footer split into two divs. The top div displays a background-image to separate it from the main page, and the second div contains the actual footer content.

It looks like the following in all browsers:

[image: Good]

...except IE6, where it looks like:

[image: Bad]

I'm guessing it's a margin/padding issue, but I can't identify which div is causing it (it's working in all browsers except IE6!).

The work-in-progress site is available [here](http://sandbox.woodstockdesigns.co.uk/), if anyone can identify where the extra space is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE6 font-size has direct effect on block elements. So, to fix this, set font-size: 0 to the #footerTop DIV.

Comment: Damn, I was close with the line-height thing. Nicely done. I'm taking note!

Comment: Any clues as to why the tiled page background image doesn't show in IE6 either (or should I ask this as a separate question?)

Comment: It looks like a PNG24 which IE6 doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nice design!

Secondly, have you tried setting the line-height to 0 in the top div? Occasionally fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, setting line-height to 0 has no effect.

Comment: You could also try making sure the "footer" div hasLayout. Set "height:1%" on it, or "zoom:1". More info: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Adding `height: 1%;` to the footer div had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try removing any spaces between the tags. This has happened to me before in IE 6. So instead of:

```
<div id="footerTop"></div>

        <div id="footer">
```

do:

```
<div id="footerTop"></div><div id="footer">
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest as well - it's a classic IE6 glitch.

Comment: not sure then... if it were me I would just add in a negative margin in your IE6 css